# Hide legend label on AmChart4

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using amchart line graph.

I want to hide amchart legend label on the graph.

I struggled to find out that there are items related to `labels`

```
console.log(chart.legend.labels.values);
console.log(chart.legend.labels.values.length)// somehow 0....

  for (key in this.chart.legend.labels.values){ // it doesn't loop...
    this.chart.legend.labels.values[key].hide();
  }
```

How can I hide the legend labels??

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer:

```js
chart.legend.labels.template.disabled = true;
```

Demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/17e8f139f06008c69ee45130718d5324

Getting to know [amCharts v4's `ListTemplate` concept](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/list-templates/) will help to understand why this answer works and how to use such an object like `chart.legend.labels` in the case you wanted to iterate over it.

A `ListTemplate` basically uses an actual instance of an object/Class as the template for all future such objects that it will generate, it stores this in its `template` property. [`chart.legend.labels`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/legend/#labels_property) is a `ListTemplate` for/of [`Label`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/)s.

By default, a chart's legend will refer to the charts' series to automatically generate legend items, it will clone `chart.legend.markers.template` and `chart.legend.labels.template` and then populate the clones with series' colors/data. So if the original label is [`disabled`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#disabled_property), it will be:

> "hidden, ... removed from any processing, layout calculations, and generally treated as if it does not exist."

This is what we want, as `.hide()` could just visually hide the text, yet still occupy the same space (thinking in CSS terms, it's a lot like `display: none` vs `visibility: hidden`).

The above process is *asynchronous*. It's why your code, `chart.legend.labels.values.length`, returns `0` if run straight away in the source, but the expected number if run directly in the console later on. If you wanted to iterate over the legend items or labels, you'd have to wait for them to be rendered, then use its [`each()`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/listtemplate/#each_method) method (instead of looping through `values`), e.g.:

```
chart.legend.events.on("inited", function() {
    chart.legend.labels.each(function(label) {
        // Do something related to this specific label
    });
});
```

In the above code, we wait for the legend itself to grab its data, parse, and render, then we check the populated labels for whatever it is we want to do.

By using the `template` in advance, we ignore the asynchronous nature altogether. If you want to apply settings on all legend labels after the fact, in the case of `chart.legend.labels.template`, it already has [`applyOnClones`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/label/#applyOnClones_property) set to `true`, so you could toggle `chart.legend.labels.template.disabled` between `true` and `false` at any time during your app and it would hide/show the legend's labels instantly each time, updating its layout accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot @notacouch!! It really helps me to understand the template. Now `chart.legend.markers.template.disabled` works well. However I have one problem. When I touch each legend object, template is not available and I need to wait for legend rendering finished, am I correct?.  My loading process is 1).making chart class instance -> 2).load data by Ajax -> 3). set data to chart and `validateData()`. however `inited` is called at process 1) . Is there any method or handler to wait for process 3)?

Comment: And also, I want to loop both labels and markers in the way you told like chart.legend.labels.each(function(label) and chart.legend.markers.each(function(label). Then, I check the label name by label.dataItem.component.dataFields.valueY. Since I have multiple series which has different valueY and the same valueX(date). However label.dataItem.component.dataFields.valueY has value though, marker.dataItem.component.dataFields.valueY has no value.(Instead, There is value on `marker.dataItem.dataContext.dataFields.valueY`)  Why this two structure is different??

Comment: Good questions. You're right, with async data, `"inited"` would already run once the legend is ready even though the data hasn't come down yet. You can try the [`"datavalidated"`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/legend/#datavalidated_event) event instead. There's also `events.once` method instead of `events.on` if you only need this to run once or uniquely per ajax call. You can also try the [`"validated"`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/legend/#validated_event) event if `"datavalidated"` runs too soon.

Comment: Off the top of my head I can't say exactly why the two are different, it is most likely related to the fact that labels are concerned with magically pulling values for string representation/display, [it checks its own `dataItem` and its parents `dataItem`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/formatting-strings/#Data_source) not within children. So e.g. `chart.legend.labels.getIndex(0).dataItem` is actually `series1.dataItem`. Markers are concerned with emulating the look/feel/behavior of their series and are more a part of Legends than anything else.

Comment: So their `dataItem` is actually a `LegendDataItem`. E.g. a legend item's container hosts the marker, label, and value label and are found via `chart.legend.itemContainers`. The first `marker` and first `itemContainer`, both have the same exact `dataItem`: `chart.legend.markers.getIndex(0).dataItem === chart.legend.itemContainers.getIndex(0).dataItem` is `true`. That `dataItem`'s `dataContext` is literally the series, e.g. `series1`. The following are equivalent: `chart.legend.labels.getIndex(0).dataItem === chart.legend.markers.getIndex(0).dataItem.dataContext.dataItem`.

Comment: It's not exactly clear to me, though, what you're trying to do. Why the label name? Why loop through both the markers and the labels?

Comment: Sorry for late reply I finally success to integrate with `datavalidated` Thank you very much. What I want to do is control two series together with the one marker and label. For example, `Main series`, `Sub series` , Main Series marker click hide/show both series.

Comment: Each series has valueY field ‘main’ and ’sub’ 

then, I loop the marker  and label.

`chart.legend.markers.each(function(marker) {
If (marker.dataItem.component.dataFields.valueY == ‘sub’){ marker.disabled = true;
}` ( do same for labels)

Comment: Thanks to your explantion. I try to understand the datastructure of amchart more. –

Comment: @whitebear You're welcome! Glad to know it was of some help. You may want to consider [making a custom legend](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/legend/#Adding_custom_items) and [defining your own click event](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/legend/#Handling_events). In that case here's how to [customize the markers, too](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/legend/#Legend_markers).